# How to make two different agents stop collision or slow down whenever they come close to one other in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I am recently working on a project, which requires to study the impact of traffic in workplace. There are two sorts of working class in the workplace i.e. workers and robots.

In order to prevent accidents in the workplace, the robots need to slow down when a worker comes closer to the robot.

Following is the resource pool i am using

[image]

As you can see, I am using robots and workers as resourcepool in the model. I know I have to do this manually because I cannot use transporter and pedestrian.

Update Part: (Sorry I was not clear) I want to use statechart that continuously monitors its surrounding for other agents and slows down as needed.

Can you help with the code that detects surrounding agents continuously?

Answer (score 0):

There is no build-in mechanism with normal `Agent` resources, as you are using.

Either you work with the Material-Handling library or you have to model this explicitly yourself in your agent types for humans and robots.

This can be done in many different ways but the easiest would be a statechart that continuously monitors its surrounding for other agents and slows down as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback sir. Can you give some hints on the code that detects other surrounding agents?

Comment: Always open new issues for new questions (and upvote the answer here if it was helpful), see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check the last part. Apologies for not being specific at the first place. Much appreciated for your patience.